# Problems wrapping JSON result in a dictionary in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to retrieve JSON and wrap it in a dictionary in swift and can't figure out what the problem is.

My swift code is:

```
let apiRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: "my api url")

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(apiRequest, queue: processingQueue) {response, data, error in
if error != nil {
    completion(results: nil,error: error)
    return
}

var JSONError : NSError?
let resultsDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: &JSONError) as? NSDictionary
if JSONError != nil {
    completion(results: nil, error: JSONError)
    return
}
    // This next line causes an error that 'unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'    
    let photosContainer = resultsDictionary!["ArrayOfPhotoDTO"] as NSDictionary
    let photosReceived = photosContainer["PhotoDTO"] as [NSDictionary]
```

If I set a breakpoint then my resultsdictionary is nil, but my data variable appears to be populated correctly.  The _bytes view shows

```
"[{\"$id\":\"1\",\"PhotoID\":57,\"JobID\":2346,\"DateAdded\":\"28/11/2014 12:00:00 AM\",\"Location\":\"Beverly Hills  (1).JPG\",\"Filename\":\"Beverly Hills  (1).JPG\",\"Caption\":\"Beverly Hills  (1).JPG\"},"
```

JSONError is nil.

If I call my API directly I get the following result:

```
[
  {
  "$id": "1",
  "PhotoID": 57,
  "JobID": 2346,
  "DateAdded": "28/11/2014 12:00:00 AM",
  "Location": "Beverly Hills  (1).JPG",
  "Filename": "Beverly Hills  (1).JPG",
  "Caption": "Beverly Hills  (1).JPG"
},
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you call your API directly in the browser you get XML?!

Comment: Ah sorry, the API returns JSON, but I'm using a browser extension to format as xml!

Comment: I really advise you to use something like SwiftyJSON to parse the results. The standard way is to verbose, which makes it really hard to track down errors. (https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

Comment: I've updated my question to show the json output

Comment: Use  SwifttyJSON my friend..

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON start with `[` which means it's an array, not dictionary.
Replace your line with:

```
let resultsArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: &JSONError) as? NSArray
```

And when you access the data make sure that you take firs element in the array:

```
let photosContainer = resultsArray![0]["ArrayOfPhotoDTO"] as NSDictionary
```

You should make sure that the array contain any object before unwrap it with `!`.

Comment: Thanks, I get the error on the second line that "NSArray does not have a member name 'subscript'"

Comment: Actually I fixed that error, the '!' was on the wrong side of the array.

Comment: I've updated the question to show the json output, even with your suggestion I'm still getting the error described in my question

Comment: @Evonet can you print out the result of the array resultsArray and remove any code after that just to find where exactly you are getting the error.